# How to select values in one column based on running sum cutoff in another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

| User Id | Device Brand | Total Minutes Consumed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 10 |
| 2 | Huawei | 6 |
| 3 | Samsung | 13 |
| 4 | Apple | 8 |
| 5 | Apple | 12 |
| 6 | Samsung | 4 |
| 7 | Samsung | 8 |
| 8 | Huawei | 11 |

So I have this above table and I wanna select only top the Device Brands which sum upto 70% of the Total Minutes for eg. in this above table the total minutes are 72.
I would want to order by Device Brands by the sum of minutes and then I want to select the top devices which cover = 72*0.7 = 50.4 minutes so I would want to select only Apple and Samsung as Apple has a total of 32 minutes and Samsung sums upto 22 minutes so 32+22> 50.4

I've tried using this code but I get an error

```
SELECT DEVICE_TYPE,RUNNING_CALL_DROPS
FROM (
SELECT DEVICE_TYPE,
CALLS_DROPS,
SUM(CALLS_DROPS)*0.85 AS CUTOFF,
Sum(CALLS_DROPS) OVER (PARTITION BY DEVICE_TYPE) AS RUNNING_CALL_DROPS
FROM VOICE_KPIS) T
WHERE RUNNING_CALL_DROPS <= CUTOFF
```

Error:Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'VOICE_KPIS.DEVICE_TYPE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Have a read of the docs about [the over clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Pay particular attention to [using it with  with aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-the-over-clause-with-aggregate-functions). Give that a shot, come back and edit your question to include what you tried if you can't work it out.

Comment: Hi @allmhuran I've modified the question with the code I tried. I should have attached in the first edit thanks for mentioning it. Can you please guide me how to resolve the error

Comment: Thanks @allmhuran for the insightful solution.

Comment: No worries, but does it actually answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is slightly tricky to understand so I'm going to break it down into steps, and then we'll put the whole thing together at the end.

Here is the schema I'm going to work with for my demo

```sql
create table usage (userid int, brand varchar(20), mins int);
```

First, obviously we're going to need the total minutes by brand, nothing complex here:

```sql
with brandUsage (brand, mins) as
(
   select   brand, 
            sum(mins)
   from     usage
   group by brand
)
```

Now we're going to query the result of that, and get the running total minutes by brand.

The order of the running total is the same as the order of the minute totals by brand we just calculated, because we want the brands with more minutes to be added to our running total first. This will be useful in a moment.

For convenience, I'm also going to calculate the "threshold" here, which is the grand total minutes multiplied by 0.7. I'm also going to return the number of minutes by brand that we calculated in the previous query, because we need it later:

```sql
runningBrandUsage (brand, mins, runningMins, thresholdMins) as
(
   select   brand,
            mins,
            sum(mins) over (order by mins desc rows unbounded preceding),
            sum(mins) over () * 0.7
   from     brandUsage
)
```

OK, the result set so far looks like this:

| brand | mins | runningMins | thresholdMins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 30 | 30 | 50.4 |
| Samsung | 25 | 55 | 50.4 |
| Huawei | 17 | 72 | 50.4 |

Now the slightly tricky bit: I'm going to ask for the rows where the running total brand minutes minus the brand minutes is less than or equal to the threshold minutes.

Why does this get what we want? Let me rephrase what we're doing here: we want to exclude rows where the the threshold has already been reached.

"Already been reached" means that the running total minutes *not including the current row* has passed the threshold.

Well, "the running total minutes not including the current row" is just the running total minutes minus the current row's minutes.

So we subtract the current minutes from the running total minutes, and use the result in our where clause:

```sql
select   brand, mins
from     runningBrandUsage
where    runningMins - mins <= thresholdMins
```

Putting it all together, with sample data:

```sql
create table usage (userid int, brand varchar(20), mins int);

insert usage
values 
(1, 'Apple     ', 10),
(2, 'Huawei    ', 6 ),
(3, 'Samsung   ', 13),
(4, 'Apple     ', 8 ),
(5, 'Apple     ', 12),
(6, 'Samsung   ', 4 ),
(7, 'Samsung   ', 8 ),
(8, 'Huawei    ', 11);

with brandUsage (brand, mins) as
(
   select   brand, 
            sum(mins)
   from     usage
   group by brand
),
runningBrandUsage (brand, mins, runningMins, thresholdMins) as
(
   select   brand,
            mins,
            sum(mins) over (order by mins desc rows unbounded preceding),
            sum(mins) over () * 0.7
   from     brandUsage
)
select   brand, mins
from     runningBrandUsage
where    runningMins - mins <= thresholdMins;
```

Which produces the following result set:

| brand | mins |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 30 |
| Samsung | 25 |